# Does the iPhone get a fixed IP address when accessing the web via the mobile phone network?

Tags: iphone, web-applications, networking

I’m guessing not, but I wondered if anyone had any experience. I imagine it could vary depending on the mobile network.

I’ll do some testing here on O2 in the UK and update the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not.  The cellular network creates a dynamic IP address for each device that joins.

Answer (score 2):

FYI - The free app "SpeedTest.net" will show you the public ip of your iphone when you run a bandwidth test.  Run it, record the ip, and run it again when in a different geographic location.  I'm betting you'll find a different ip.

Comment: Nice, I was going to be mucking about with my web server’s access logs. Is that Speedtest from Xtreme Labs?

Comment: Actually, I use the one from Ookla.  They run the site SpeedTest.net which does the same thing from a browser. I'll fix the post to reflect the corrected name.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on which 'carrier box'(as I call the weird boxes in the ground owned by version or sprint) if you connect to a certain 'carrier box' it will give you the ip that that box has. lets say there is two boxes - box 1 has the IP address of 192.25.1.100, the box two might have an IP address of 192.26.1.100.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected through the 3G/EDGE network, then you should probably use a fixed ip.
And probably be behind some proxies.
If it's not a fixed ip, then there are just a few i guess.

But it should depends on where you are.
My provider does this... at least when i checked it on some 'whatismyip' website..
I always got the same when connected over the network.

I guess it depends on where you caught the network, it will probably be the same if you stay in the same place.

Comment: Your operator is most probably then NATting your address. Try to connect with two phones simultaneously and go to whatsmyip.